# Magento 1.9 Error 503 on user login, but only on some random accounts

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, debugging

Some of the users of my shop experience a 503 'Service unavailable' error when trying to log in or reset their passwords.

- if a user gets the 503, the same account keeps getting the error, until I reset the password from admin panel
- accounts getting the error are not special in any way (default customer group only, common mail addresses, more-or-less secure passwords, some accounts are confirmed already, others are not, various browsers are used.
- the 503 page represented is NOT the magento one, it is more of a page provided by the hosting company
- error appears on both apache and litespeed server, with various caching on and off
- digging into code I found that the loginPostAction gets through to Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->regenerateSessionId() method, which fails at

```
    session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Accounts with working login get a new session Id at logging in, but the 'broken' ones don't. I can reproduce the issue on the very same browser with different login data.

When running strace on index.php while running a 503-causing login, i get the following output:

```
stat("/home/myhome/public_html/index.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3146, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/sysconfig/64bit_strstr_via_64bit_strstr_sse2_unaligned", 0x7ffeb2f2ff70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=1}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_UNLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=1}) = 0
munmap(0x7ffb31a64000, 3178)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffb31a65000, 4096)            = 0
getcwd("/home/myhome", 4096)          = 15
access("/home/myhome/includes/config.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/myhome/app/Mage.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("downloader", 0x7ffeb2f30c60)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "/home/myhome/app/Mage.php was "..., 41/home/myhome/app/Mage.php was not found) = 41
```

Right now I am stuck with debugging this. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it finally: a bunch of event observers were causing in infinite loop under very special circumstances, a bad combination of products in cart, applied cart rules and active cart rules.

And right in the middle the  Ced_MauticIntegration_Model_Observer::sendAbandonedCartDetails() re-initializing the quote building process.

Issue was 'solved' by deactivating the 'abandoned cart' feature of the Mautic crm integration.